# Python code stucks in Iterating although it found the solution

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, prime-factoring

I'm trying to write a python code to find the prime factors of any given number

```
def pf(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0: #find the factors
            for j in range(2,i): #check if the factor is prime
                if i%j==0:
                    break
            else: #find the prime ones
                print(i)
```

My problem is that this code works fine with small numbers however with big numbers i have to interrupt the execution
for example:

```
pf(600851475143)
71
839
1471
6857
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    pf(600851475143)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 2, in pf
    for i in range(2,n):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

the prime factors of this big number were found in less than a second, so my question is how to tweak **this** code to stop unnecessary iterations after finding the factors with the use of the *for* not the *while* loop

Comment: Well how do you know you *have* found all the prime factors? For a start, note that you can stop at e.g. `sqrt(i)`, and that `2` is the only even prime.

Comment: because no matter you wait it's the same result, after 1 second or 30 minutes

Comment: You could start by finding the factors of very small numbers and see if it works there

Comment: @Dear_user sorry, I mean: *"how do you decide **programatically** that you've found them all?"* To tell a computer to do something, you need to be able to do it yourself. You *could* code that if no more have been found in some defined time period, stop there, for example - that would be how to model your current thought process.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: i got you the 1st time, i can't know that it found them all, for this one by testing only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed things up by dividing `n` by the obtained value in each iteration step. This way you decrease the number you are iterating. I would implement something like this (not yet sure if this is optimal and results in the lowest number of operations):

```
from math import sqrt

def pf(n):
    if n == 1: 
        return
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(2)
        pf(n/2)
        return
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            for j in range(3, int(sqrt(i))+1, 2):
                if i % j == 0:
                    break
            else:
                print(i)
                pf(n/i)
                return
    print(n)
```

Note, if using the improvement of looping until the root of the number we omit the case that the number itself is a prime number. However, if the function does not result any prime factors it is save to assume that the input is a prime number itself.

The `return` statements stop the main loop (and the function) after the recursive call. So each call of the function only results in one value and a call for the function on the result of the division of the number by its found prime.

If you make a set with all the prime numbers and check if the value is in this set you will win some time, instead of looping over all values.

Compared to the [non-recursive solution by jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27148932/3001761) this one is almost four times as fast:

```
>>> print timeit.timeit("pf(600851475143)", setup="from __main__ import pf", number=1)
71
839
1471
6857
0.00985789299011
>>> print timeit.timeit("pf2(600851475143)", setup="from __main__ import pf2", number=1)
71
839
1471
6857
0.0450129508972
```

The implementation is limited by the overflow limit of `range()`, which results in an overflow for the input value `(600851475143**2)+1`. More details on the maximum size for `range` can be found in this question:  [Python: Range() maximum size; dynamic or static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247973/python-range-maximum-size-dynamic-or-static)

A possible issue with this solution could be that the maximum recursion depth is achieved. For more details on that visit this question: [Maximum recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth)

Comment: i used this trick too when i used to list the answers in a list and it took a long time too

Comment: based on the question I thought he only wanted them to be printed and not create a generator.

Comment: @Dear_user I added the timing results for a case on my computer. About 28 miliseconds for a value or order `10^12`.

Comment: @tvandenbrande testing for e.g. `pf(360)` (hint: or any even `n`) causes `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`. Also, you will hit the recursion limit for numbers with large numbers of prime factors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Found the issue, didn't paste my latest working code here. Forgot to add the prime check. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, your revision works fine for me - the recursive approach is very neat. Note that you can make it faster by adopting the `range` arguments used in my answer - `for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2):` and `for j in range(3, int(sqrt(i)+1), 2):`. Also, using `for: else:` (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) is neater than having a `prime` flag. With these revisions I get 0.03s for recursive vs 0.04s for yours unmodified and 0.14s for mine. Note another slight difference - mine prints only unique prime factors.

Comment: I would prefer to get the full decomposition and not the unique primes. This way you can recompose the input and check if your result is correct. 
Good hint about the `for: else:` notation. It even improves speed (from 11.9 ms to 9.9 ms on my system)

Comment: Interestingly, I have further found that the primality check is unnecessary - because of the way your approach works, the first factor found at each step is prime. I haven't yet convinced myself that this is always true, but haven't yet found a counter example. That would save further processing time. I agree that the full decomposition is useful - again, more so if the list were returned.

Comment: Was googling a bit on your comment (is the prime check necessary) and found this interesting wiki with an example code that is even faster: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Prime_decomposition#Python

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding prime factors to a list as you find them, and see if they multiply to make the number you are trying to factorize, but I think that might add more time than it would save.

As suggested in the comments, you could also stop at the square root of the number - using `for i in range(2, sqrt(n) + 1):`.

In terms of generally speeding it up you could also try creating a set of primes, and adding to it when you find them in the 5th line. Example:

```
if i in primes:
   print(i)
else:
    for j in range(2,i):   # check if the factor is prime
        if i%j==0:
            break
```

Comment: and how long the list of primes should be?  and about the sqrt(n) suggestion is relatively helpful (for example what is i want pf(n**2), your first suggestion is the best and i have to write a code to multiply the factors each time and compare it to the number inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

One further point - use xrange() rather than range(), so you do not internally create the list of all numbers to iterate: (if you are using Python 2 !)

[What is the difference between range and xrange functions in Python 2.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x)

Comment: The presence of parentheses in the `print` statement is *usually* indicative of Python3.

Answer (score 0):

just iterate square root of value, this is how you can iterate through less nombers and
use `generators` to skip repeated iteration usinf `for else`

```
from math import sqrt
def pf(n):
    n = int(sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(2, n): # in python2 use `range` for python3
        for j in xrange(2,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield i # this will return when prime nomber will found.

print list(pf(4356750))
```

Comment: @Dear_user check the solution.

Comment: Why use `xrange` for one loop and `range` for the other?

Comment: for the sqrt it is not always helpful, suppose the original number is squared, and for xrange i am using python3

Comment: @Dear_user still after squaring you will have to search till that nomber, and `range` is same as `xrange` in python3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
from math import sqrt

def pf(n):
    """Print the prime factors of n."""
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(2)
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2):
        if n % i == 0: # i is a factor of n
            for j in range(3, int(sqrt(i))+1, 2):
                if i % j == 0:
                    break
            else: # i is also prime
                print(i)
```

By factoring out the checks for `2` you can almost halve the search space, and using the fact that all prime factors must be below the square root of a number you cut it down even further. This takes about a quarter of a second for `600851475143`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("pf(600851475143)", setup="from __main__ import pf", number=1)
71
839
1471
6857
0.27306951168483806
```

Another option would be to use a prime sieve to generate all primes below `n`, then filter out those that are also factors of `n` (effectively the reverse operation).

Comment: thanks this one is helpful for example number (12-digits number) however i tried it for (600851475143**2)+1 and it stuck

Comment: @Dear_user no kidding - that's 3.6e23, for which you have to check through `600851475144` candidate factors and `24` actual factors; its [largest prime factor is `171015606064053029`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+factors+of+(600851475143**2)%2B1), to determine the primality of which you have to check `413540332` candidate divisors. If factoring numbers that large were easy, [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) would be in serious trouble.

Comment: A problem I noticed, also with my answer is that if n itself is a prime, the result is not included.

Comment: @tvandenbrande this has the same issue - one fix would be to return a list of prime factors, rather than printing within the function; if that's empty, you know `n` is itself prime. This also makes the function more useful in other contexts.